# Solving a functional equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:ℂ→ℂ$ be a function.

(a) How I can solve this functional equation:

$f(b-s)+f(s)=0,b∈ℝ$ with respect to $f$ and $b=1$.

Comment: In part (a), what do you mean by "and $b=1$". Should the equation simply read $f(b-s) + f(s) = 0$?

Comment: No, I mean the case: $f(1-s)+f(s)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) For $s=\frac {1}{2}$, we have $f(\frac {1}{2}) +f(\frac {1}{2}) = 0$ , so we must have $f( \frac {1}{2}) =0$.

Consider $S = (\frac {1}{2}, \infty) \times (-\infty, \infty) \cup \frac {1}{2} \times (0, \infty)$.

Define $f(s): S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ however you wish. It does not even need to be continuous.

Consider $ T = \mathbb{C} \setminus S \setminus  (\frac {1}{2},0)$

For $t \in T, 1-t \in S$, and so we define $ f(t) = -f(1-t)$. This then clearly satisfies your condition.

For (b), do the same with similar sets.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin : Thank you very much for this answer. As far I a can see the only property of $f$ is to be an odd function. You determined only the set where the equation holds.

Comment: By setting $g(s)=f((1/2)+s)$

Comment: @ Calvin Lin: By the set $ T = \mathbb{C} \setminus S \setminus (0, \frac {1}{2})$ you mean in inside: $S$ minus the two points not the interval $(0, \frac {1}{2})$.

Comment: @RH1 Should have been $(\frac {1}{2},0)$, which is the complex plane representation for $\frac {1}{2} + 0i$. Like you mentioned, all we need is the odd function, after the translation, to exploit the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: @  Calvin Lin: One last thing: How you obtain the set $S$.

Comment: @RH1 Think about the symmetry, which you stated as "$g$ is an odd function. You could create the sets $S$ and $T$ in a variety of ways.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin: But still have trouble with this.

Comment: @RH1 Go to the math chat room, will be easier to discuss there. I'm heading off to sleep soonish though.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin: In the set $S = (\frac {1}{2}, \infty) \times (-\infty, \infty) \cup \frac {1}{2} \times (0, \infty)$. Is the part $(1/2)×(0,∞)$ is an open set (not containing $(1/2))$. Should'nt $S$ be $S=((1/2)+i0)∪(((1/2),∞)×ℝ)∪((1/2)×(0,∞))$.

Comment: @CalvinLin:   
Hello, again, What about the case when I know that $f:C→C$ is defined in the whole complex plane. Does this affect the fact that its domain of definition maust be $S$ as you answred the question.